# alert not showing jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What could be wrong with my code.
when I click the text enclosed with anchor tags. alert function is not showing up.
but when i try console.log();

it shows the id in the console.

I generated the table data with php.

please help.

thanks

```
<tbody>
    <?php
         include('config.php');
         $qry = $handler->prepare( "SELECT * FROM inspection WHERE inspect_status = ?");
         $qry->execute(array('Booked'));
         $row = $qry->rowCount();
         while($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

           $iid = $row['inspect_id'];
           $service = $row['inspect_service'];
           $refno = $row['inspect_refnum'];
           $insdate = $row['inspect_date'];
           $intrno = $row['inspect_internalrno'];
           $inspect_status = $row['inspect_status'];
          ?>
    <?php
            echo"
              <tr>
                 <td>$iid</td>
                 <td>$refno</td>
                 <td>$intrno</td>
                 <td>$service</td>
                 <td>$insdate</td>
                 <td>
                  <a idd=$iid class='marks' href='?i=$iid'>Confirm</a>
                 </td>
               </tr>
               ";  
               ?>
    <?php } ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('body').delegate('.marks', 'click', function () {
                var idconf = $(this).attr('idd');
                alert(idconf);
                return false;

            });
        });
    </script>


</tbody>
```

Comment: FYI `idd` is an invalid attribute.

Comment: It's not an _official_ html attribute, but it can be used nonetheless as custom attribute. Ask Angular.

Comment: I can't see why `console.log` would work while `alert` doesn't. Can you give us a working example? This one works - http://jsfiddle.net/425g3sta/

Comment: why `.delegate()` & not `.on()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rather use `.on()` for event delegation:

```
 $('body').on('click','.marks',function(){
          var idconf = $(this).attr('idd');
          alert(idconf);
         return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$('.marks').on('click', function(e) {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    return false;
})
```

And change -

```
<a id=$iid class='marks' href='?i=$iid'>Confirm</a>
```

If you dont want to use id then you can try `data` attribute also.